# How do I leave a location in Wasteland?

Tags: wasteland

I have started playing Wasteland for the first time and I'm trying to figure out the controls. While the [guide](http://wasteland.protozoic.com/) has been very helpful, I can't seem to find how to leave a location.

For example, I have helped the farmers at the agricultural centre, and I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 3):

Walk to the edge of the location and the game will prompt you as you try to walk off the map: "Do you want to leave this location Y/N". Type 'Y'.

In the specific case referenced, the exit to the ag center back to the world map is the same place you entered from: the middle of the East side of the map.